# Is there a way to create a dynamic edge collection?

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection in this format:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'test', 
        'features': ['features/id', 'features/id2'...]
    }
]
```

I want to create a dynamic edge collection which connects between documents that has the same features.
For example, if I have this collection:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'test', 
        'features': ['features/id', 'features/id2']
    },
    {
        'name': 'test2', 
        'features': ['features/id2']
    },
    {
        'name': 'test3', 
        'features': ['features/id']
    },
]
```

The edge collection will automatically create these connections: test <-> test2; test <-> test3

Comment: I don't quite understand the desired data model `test <-> test2; test <-> test3`. The standard interpretation of this syntax would be to have a vertex collection for each name (test, test2, test3) and edges between test vertices in an unnamed edge collection. That does not match up with your request for dynamic edge collections. Are you asking whether the system can automatically create edges to link up matching features? If so, then the answer is no, but you can run a one-off query to create edges. Depending on how you want to query the data later, this might not even be necessary however.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create collections with AQL. What you can do though is to

- use a single edge collection and store attributes such as the name on edges to filter by it later in queries
- run a query to determine the distinct edge collection names, create an edge collection for each name via arangosh, the HTTP API or a driver and also run a query for each to create edges in the respective edge collection

Also see https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/graphs.html#multiple-edge-collections-vs-filters-on-edge-document-attributes

I don't think that this is what you are asking for however (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66300641/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-dynamic-edge-collection#comment117237494_66300641)).